# What is the super heart location in level 3-3

Tags: charlie-the-duck

[Charlie the Duck](http://store.steampowered.com/app/691250/Charlie_the_Duck/) is a old school platform game from 1996 that was recently made available again on Steam. When I played this as a child I did not find all the hidden secrets in the game, so I was enthousiastic to give it a try.

So far I found all the super hearts in all levels, except for the last one. On the steam page there is actually [a screenshot](http://cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/691250/ss_a6f1a5eef6915f20adbb2775577bdb0e323641c6.1920x1080.jpg?t=1506082730) of this level where you can see three hearts. This proves that it is possible to find the heart before you get to the point in the image, which is at about 1/3 of the level.

Could somebody point out or hint at the location of the super heart in this level? I spent like two hours trying to find it in the game itself. I also spent about 15 minutes searching online, but because the original game is so old and the steam version so new, I can't find anything.

I did find [this full playthrough](https://youtu.be/gUy0E2zScGA?t=35m1s) of the original version, but the author didn't find the super heart either.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the location myself, it took a while but I got it :).

> [image: Third heart location]

Comment: I can't get up that platform on Android.

Comment: @RichardLindhout If you start on the far left in the level, you have to get up the first platform. From there on you have to jump your way from platform to platform. You have to make speed for some of the jumps to work.